# Update parent class in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm a Vue.js noob and trying to figure out how to toggle a class inside a for loop for the parent of the link that is clicked.

I want to click on the "Advanced" link and then toggle a class of overlay for the `section` and `.advanced-fields` elements only in that section. I know I can add the onOff data attribute to each section but I am saving to a database and don't want to add in unnecessary data fields.

Can anyone point me in the right direction. Thanks.

Here is a simplified version of my code.

```
<div id="app">
    <section v-bind:class="{ overlay: onOff }" v-for="section in sections">
        <a href="#0" @click.prevent="showAdvanced(section)">Advanced</a>

        <div class="advanced-fields" v-bind:class="{ overlay: onOff }" v-show="onOff">
            <fieldset>
                <label>
                    ID
                    <input type="text" name="section[id]">
                </label>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <label>
                    Class
                    <input type="text" name="section[css_class]">
                </label>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>

<script>
new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data:{
        "sections": [
            {
                "id": "section-1",
                "css_class": ""
            },
            {
                "id": "section-2",
                "css_class": ''
            }
        ],
        "onOff": false
    },
    methods: {
        showAdvanced: function(section) {
            this.onOff = !this.onOff;
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Almost exactly the same question and answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44598666/7636961

Comment: Thanks @wostex that helped me figure it out, I'll post my updated code below in case anyone else comes across this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer [Vue bind click that adds active class (and removes from the last one)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44598187/vue-bind-click-that-adds-active-class-and-removes-from-the-last-one/44598666#44598666) helped me figure it out.

https://jsfiddle.net/ferne97/n1hfde94/

Here is the updated code that works properly.

```
<div id="app">
    <section v-bind:class="{ overlay: index == isActive }" v-for="(section, index) in sections">
        <a href="#0" @click.prevent="showAdvanced(index)">Advanced</a>

        <div class="advanced-fields" v-bind:class="{ overlay: index == isActive }" v-show="index == isActive">
            <fieldset>
                <label>
                    ID
                    <input type="text" name="section[id]" v-model="section.id">
                </label>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <label>
                    Class
                    <input type="text" name="section[css_class]" v-model="section.css_class">
                </label>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </section>

    <pre>{{ $data }}</pre>
</div>

<script>
new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data:{
        "sections": [
            {
                "id": "section-1",
                "css_class": ""
            },
            {
                "id": "section-2",
                "css_class": ''
            }
        ],
        "isActive": null
    },
    methods: {
        showAdvanced: function(index) {
            this.isActive = this.isActive === index ? null : index
        }
    }
});
</script>
```